# Laravel Eloquent: How can I define this relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
lessons
- lessonID
- lessonName
..

sections
- sectionID
- lessonID references lessons.lessonID
..

exercises
- exerciseID
- sectionID references sections.sectionID
..
```

I have set up the following relations:

Lesson:

```
public function sections()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Section', 'lessonID');
}
```

Section:

```
public function lesson() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Lesson', 'lessonID');
}

public function exercise() {
    return $this->hasOne('Exercise', 'sectionID');
}
```

Exercise:

```
public function section() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Section', 'sectionID');
}
```

Now I want to say that a Lesson has many Exercises through Sections, so I tried adding

```
public function exercises()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Exercise', 'Section', 'lessonID', 'sectionID');
}
```

to the Lessons model and I run

`Lesson::with('sections', 'exercises')`

gives me an empty array for the exercises. How can I accomplish what I want?

Edit: I'm seeding the Exercise table like so:

```
<?php

class ExerciseTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
    {
    DB::table('exercises')->delete();

    Exercise::create(array(
        'exerciseID' => 1,
        'sectionID' => 2,
        ...
        ));

    Exercise::create(array(
        'exerciseID' => 2,
        'sectionID' => 4,
        ...
        ));

    }
}

?>
```

Edit 2: Here's my models: http://laravel.io/bin/2Rdl

And here are the query logs: http://laravel.io/bin/vebK

So in short: **The Lesson and its Sections are returned fine, but I get an empty array for the Exercises.**

Comment: what you mean by 'works but gives me null...' what is the exact output?

Comment: It gives me the data for the Lesson and its Sections but an empty array for the exercises. My apologies, I edited the post.

Comment: it should work then, pls paste every relation you described

Comment: @deczo: Updated the question with the relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I reported the issue on [their Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4018#issuecomment-39121593), I got an embarrassingly simple answer: the request should be `Lesson::with('sections.exercises')` instead.

Comment: ok, but this is another solution which is not related to hasManyThrough. That's a nested with

Comment: I see... this is all new and confusing for me. I have closed the ticket on their Github though.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine to me as you set it up now, after @deczo's help. Probalby you just don't have any related entry, which could be the reason for an empty array

**EDIT**

Seems that the `hasManyThrough` function is not supposed to be used in this situation.

Given that the relations are set correctly (as you confirm in the comments to this answer), the answer is to be found in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through). It clearly states

> For example, a Country model might have many Posts through **a** Users
>   model

I believe that the relation for which `hasManyThrough` is intended for a ONE-to-ONE + ONE-to-MANY. In your case is ONE-to-MANY + ONE-to-ONE, which might be why it doesn't work.

I would suggest you to report this issue to the [github page](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues?page=1&state=open).

Comment: What do you mean by related entry? All of the tables are populated using seeds.

Comment: That's what I figured, but there could be the possibility that there are no excercises related to a specific lesson due to IDs seeding. Could this be the case?

Comment: I have a lesson with lessonID 1, some sections with sectionIDs 1-10, all have lessonID 1 and finally some exercises with exerciseIDs 1 and 2, but sectionIDs 2 and 4.

Comment: Just as a stupid check, do you get anything if you don't eager load and just var_dump the excercises looping through the sections you get from `Lesson::find(1)->sections`?

Comment: @pg-robban, check my updated unswer. I think that's the reason why it doesn't work ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I don't eager load, it works as I expect, but that will leave me with an extra query and some ugly coding on the client side. Sorry if I misunderstood you, but I could change the hasOne to hasMany in Section->exercise and it still gives me an empty array. This will give me a One-to-one + One-To-Many, like you say, wouldn't it?

Comment: no, because a lesson has many sections. In order for this to work, a lesson must have one section, which can have many exercises.

Comment: Ah right, I was thinking backwards. I will upvote this answer and mark it as answered if nobody comes with a better solution when the bounty has ended.

Comment: I reported it on their Github and got an embarrassingly simple solution, which seems to be working. I posted it here and marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here lies the problem:

```
public function exercise() {
    return $this->hasOne('Exercise', 'Section');
}
```

should be:

```
public function exercise() {
    return $this->hasOne('Exercise', 'sectionID');
}
```

edit:

Your hasManyThrough relation was wrong too. It goes like this:

```
hasManyThrough('farModel', 'relatedModel', 'keyOnRelatedModel', 'keyOnFarModel')
```

so correct:

```
public function exercises()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Exercise', 'Section', 'lessonID', 'sectionID');
}
```

---

edit: 
to @clod986 note - hasManyThrough() works just the same for ONE-TO-MANY -> ONE-TO-ONE as long as the latter is hasOne (not belongsTo) relation.

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately, I still receive an empty array.

Comment: Changed, still empty array.

Comment: Are you certain you have valid data in your database?

Comment: Well, everything has been seeded using seed classes, so it should be correct. And I verified by looking in PhpMyAdmin, didn't see anything wrong there.

Comment: those models look just fine, try running this in PHPMyAdmin or plain MySQL

Comment: Sorry, but running what?

Comment: the query built by laravel. You can get it by calling DB::getQueryLog() for example