# hasmanythrough relation not working

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent

I'm creating a messaging application by using laravel. i have used four migrations(users, conversations, conversationsmember and conversationsreply). i have also defined relationships between models.

Details of user will be stored in the users table. Conversations id will be stored in the conversations table. Each conversation will have members. The details of members will be stored in the conversationsmember table and finally the reply will be stored in the conversationsreply table.

Now i was trying to show all conversations of a particular user(i have used hasManyThrough relationship between User and ConversationMembers model), but it's not working.

here are the details:

Users migration:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->string('name', 32);
$table->string('username', 32);
$table->string('email', 320);
$table->string('password', 64);

$table->timestamps();
```

Conversations migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
```

conversationsmembers migration:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('conversation_id');
$table->integer('user_id'); 

$table->timestamps();
```

conversationsreply migrations

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('conversation_id');
$table->integer('user_id'); 

$table->timestamps();
```

User model:
 i have added these methods to default User model

```
public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Conversation', 'ConversationsMember', 'conversation_id', 'id');
    }

    public function conversationsMember(){
        return $this->hasMany('ConversationsMember', 'user_id', 'id');
    }


    public function conversationsReply(){
        return $this->hasMany('ConversationsReply', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Conversation model

```
class Conversation extends Eloquent{


    public function conversationsMember(){
        return $this->hasMany('ConversationsMember', 'conversation_id', 'id');
    }
    public function conversationsReply(){
        return $this->hasMany('ConversationReply');
    }
}
```

ConversationsMember model

```
    class ConversationsMember extends Eloquent{

        protected $fillable = array('conversation_id', 'user_id');

        protected $table = 'conversationsmember';

        public function users(){
            return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
        }

        public function conversations(){
            return $this->belongsTo('Conversation', 'conversation_id', 'id');
        }

}
```

ConversationsReply Model

```
class ConversationsReply extends Eloquent{

    protected $fillable = array('reply', 'user_id','conversation_id', 'ip');

    protected $table = 'conversationsreply';

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function conversations(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Conversation', 'conversation_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining what 'not working' means. Error? No results? Weird results?

Comment: when i'm calling conversation method via User model, nothing is happening. i used print_r to see the results and it showed two braces()

Comment: Okay looking at your schema and code it looks like you're either using `hasManyThrough` incorrectly or modelling your data incorrectly. As I understand it, `hasManyThrough` is used when `X` has many `Y` and then `Y` has many `Z` and you want to get all `Z`s for a given `X`. As such, your schema needs to have `x_id` on `Y` and `y_id` on `Z`. If that's not what you're looking for but actually `X` has many `Y` and `Y` has many `X`, then you need `belongsToMany` rather than `hasManyThrough`. It seems like the latter is what you want based on your schema (you have a pivot table). Maybe try that.

Comment: Also be sure to follow [the conventions](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) for table and column spellings (and pluralisation).

Comment: @alexrussell, I think it's X hasOne Y, Y hasMany Z. Check this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720311/laravel-eloquent-how-can-i-define-this-relationship/22758290#22758290

Comment: @clod986 fair enough, I haven't had the opportunity to use `hasManyThrough` yet, but still my point remains that @user170654's DB schema suggests a simple `belongsToMany` between `User` and `Conversation` whereas the code wants a `hasManyThrough` and that's probably the source of the issue.

Comment: Agreed. I believe it's a situation where OP should use Many-To-Many between User and Conversation with attached data.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but from what you wrote it looks like you can code in a much simpler way.

I would suggest you to consider using ConversationMembers as a pivot table between Users and Conversations, defining a a Many-to-Many relationship. You can find all the info you are looking for [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).